# Find the fourier series of a piecewise continuous function

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform

> Consider the function 
>   $f(x) =
> \begin{cases}
> 0 & & x \in [-\pi, 0) \\
> 1 & & x \in [0, \frac{\pi}{2})\\
> 0 & & x \in [\frac{\pi}{2}, \pi)\\
> \end{cases}$
>   Calculate its fourier series

I am unsure if this is correct but i have:

$a_0=\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)dx=\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}1dx=\frac{1}{2\pi}[x]_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}=\frac{1}{4}$

$a_n=\frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)\cos(nx)dx=\frac{1}{\pi} \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos(nx)dx=\frac{1}{\pi}[\frac{1}{n}\sin(nx)]_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}=\frac{1}{n\pi}$

$b_n=\frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)\sin(nx)dx=\frac{1}{\pi} \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin(nx)dx=\frac{1}{\pi}[\frac{1}{n}(-\cos(nx))]_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}=\frac{-1}{n\pi}$

So we have $f(x)=\frac{1}{4}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}[\frac{1}{n\pi} \cos(nx) - \frac{1}{\pi} \sin(nx)]$

Is this correct?

---

Comment: it should be ${ a_{0}={\frac {1}{\pi }}\int \limits _{-\pi }^{\pi }f(x)dx,}$,not $\frac { 1 }{ 2\pi  } \\ $

Answer (score 1):

The setup is alright but the evaluations are not correct. For example
$$
\dfrac{1}{\pi} \int_0^{\pi/2} \sin(nx) \; dx = \dfrac{1 - \cos(n \pi/2)}{n \pi}  \neq - \dfrac{1}{n \pi}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Looks OK to me,
although you lost the
1/n term in the sine series.

As long as you can do the integration,
you can find the Fourier series
of any piecewise continuous function
exactly as you have done here.

Answer (score 0):

It should be $$\\ { a }_{ 0 }=\frac { 1 }{ 2 } \\ { a }_{ n }=\frac { \sin { \left( \frac { \pi n }{ 2 }  \right)  }  }{ n\pi  } \\ { b }_{ n }=\frac { 1-\cos { \left( \frac { \pi n }{ 2 }  \right)  }  }{ n\pi  } \\ \\ \\ $$